Azure API Error "The request is throttled because you have exceeded the concurrent request limit allowed for your sub websocket error code: 4429"

First, I signed up for the Azure free plan.
Then I used the Azure Text to Speech API from Node.js to successfully make calls on the free plan.
I made about 5000 successful calls (yay).
I get the error message The request is throttled because you have exceeded the concurrent request limit allowed for your sub websocket error code: 4429.
(I still have $200 in free credits and 29 days left on the free plan)
Try again an hour later, get the same error.
Try again a day later, get the same error.
Subscribe to the $29/month plan, test the API again, get the same error.
Wait an hour, try the API again, get the same error.
Submit a support ticket, wait a day, then try again, and get the same error!

What is the deal! What am I doing wrong!? How can I debug this? Why isn't it working?
I am making 1 request at a time as well, when I make a request, I wait for it to finish, then immediately make the next request (in an async loop in Node.js). I don't think that has anything to do with concurrent request limits, as I am not making more than 1 concurrent request at a time.
Plus, I waited for 1-2 days, or at least an hour, before trying again, and it still doesn't work. I would expect the concurrency limit to be reset after at most an hour, but it's definitely not resetting.
Lastly, as you can see in the code below, I tried waiting 500ms between requests, but even the first request fails with the same error message, so doesn't matter if there is a pause in between them right now it seems.
Any ideas?
import 'dotenv/config'

import sdk from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk'

import fs from 'fs'
import { parse } from 'csv-parse/sync'
import talk from '@termsurf/talk'

const terms = parse(
  fs.readFileSync(
    `tibetan.syllable.csv`,
    `utf-8`,
  ),
  { columns: true },
)

const TERMS = terms.reduce((m: any, x: any) => {
  if (x.pronunciation.trim().match(/[\s\/]|a~/)) return m
  m[x.word] = {
    talk: x.pronunciation.trim(),
    ipa: talk.default.talk.toIPA(x.pronunciation.trim()),
  }
  return m
}, {})

// This example requires environment variables named "SPEECH_KEY" and "SPEECH_REGION"

call()

async function call() {
  for (const term in TERMS) {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500))
    // continue
    const { talk, ipa } = TERMS[term]
    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      String(process.env.SPEECH_KEY),
      String(process.env.SPEECH_REGION),
    )

    // The language of the voice that speaks.
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = talk.match(/c/i)
      ? 'en-US-AndrewMultilingualNeural'
      : 'hi-IN-KunalNeural' // hi-IN-AaravNeural

    const path = `tmp/tibetan/kunal/${term}-${talk}.mp3`
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
      continue
    }

    console.log(term, TERMS[term])

    // const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(path)

    // Create the speech synthesizer.
    const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(
      speechConfig,
      // audioConfig,
    )

    const ssml = `<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
  <voice name="${speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName}">
    <prosody rate="slow">
      <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="${ipa}">${talk}</phoneme>
    </prosody>
  </voice>
</speak>`

    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // Start the synthesizer and wait for a result.
      synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
        ssml,
        function (result) {
          if (result.errorDetails) {
            console.error(result.errorDetails)
          } else {
            // console.log(result)

            fs.writeFileSync(path, new Uint8Array(result.audioData))
          }

          synthesizer.close()

          res(undefined)
        },
        function (err) {
          console.trace(err)
          synthesizer.close()
          rej(err)
        },
      )
    })
  }
}

Update
I found that there is a distinction between the $29/month subscription, and paying for the service with the "pricing tier" page. So I applied the standard tier, like this. Now it's allowing me some requests, but I am getting the error once every 3 requests or so. How do I make it so I can make unlimited requests as fast as I want?


Did you find an answeR?

Switching to the standard pricing tier was the only solution, took about 30 minutes for it to kick in as well.
